# Using Git Sub Modules to manage 3rd party dependencies?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm currently running a test to see how Git sub modules work in the hope that I can use them to manage 3rd party dependencies.

In my local test I have a folder with my main Git repo in it. I then have a sub folder called `scripts` which has a sub module created for the GitHub repo https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/

When I initially set-up the sub module I obviously got ALL the files/folders within that 3rd party repo but the only file I was interested in was the `require.js` file (https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js) I commited my changes including all redundant files/folders deleted and then waited for RequireJs to make a change to their code.

When the change happened I `git pull`ed in and it seems that every file changed would get pulled down? Even though in my repo I had commited them as deleted it seems that the sub module would regardless pull down any files that had changed even though I clearly didn't want them.

So that is problem one. The second problem is I then delete the files again and go to commit but I can't commit because of merge issues? But I can't merge them because I've deleted them! I've seen this before and apparently the solution was to go into a specific .git folder and delete out the files so they couldn't be referenced but this just seems like a lot of work to manage 3rd party dependencies?

I just want to clone down a repo, delete any files I don't want and run a `git pull` whenever I hear about an update to the 3rd party code. Is there any way to achieve that, simply?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: How to clone a 3rd party library into a subdirectory of my app's repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960960/git-how-to-clone-a-3rd-party-library-into-a-subdirectory-of-my-apps-repository)

Answer (score 3):

> When the change happened I git pulled in and it seems that every file changed would get pulled down?

Sure it does: your parent repo still has a reference to the upstream `jrburke/requirejs` repo with a SHA1 referencing its full content.

If you really wanted to managed a modified version of that repo as a submodule, you would need to:

- fork that repo
- add your fork as a submodule
- remove all  files but one
- git commit within that submodule, and push to your fork
- add as a new remote named 'requirejs', pointing to `jrburke/requirejs` repo
- get back to your parent repo and commit again (to record the new state of your submodule)

Then, within the submodule, you can '`git fetch requirejs`', merge only the file that interest you to your own version, commit and push that to your fork.
As always, don't forget to go back to your parent repo, and commit again.

Comment: thanks for this information - I'm trying this out now but I'm still fairly new to the finer points of Git. After I 'fetch' how do I merge just the single file I'm interested in? `git merge require.js`?

Comment: tried that but it didn't appear to do anything? `git checkout requirejs/master /require.js` (the file `require.js` is in the root of the repo). No error is shown so it looks to have succeeded in some way? but if I run `git status` I don't see any updates to commit?

Comment: @Integralist has the content of `require.js` changed at all after that checkout? And were you *already* on `master` when you did that checkout?

Comment: I was on my own 'master' branch when I executed that command. require.js has had an update since I originally forked the project

Comment: @Integralist strange, then `require.js` should have been updated.

Comment: You can't merge a file.  You can grab the active state of the file with: `$ git checkout <ref> -- require.js`. This will overwrite any change to that file in your working copy on whatever branch you're on. `git merge` operates on commits, not on files.